# Python logging: How can i use the root logger when no logger cfg is available for specific loggers

Tags: python, logging

I have configured logging using a yaml cfg file:

```
version: 1
disable_existing_loggers: true

formatters:
    default:
        format: "[%(process)d] %(name)s(%(funcName)s:%(lineno)s) - %(levelname)s: %(message)s"

handlers:
    syslog:
        class: logging.handlers.SysLogHandler
        level: DEBUG
        formatter: default
        address: [192.168.0.100, 514]
        facility: local0

    rotating_file:
        class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
        level: DEBUG
        formatter: default
        filename: file.log
        maxBytes: 10485760 # 10MB
        backupCount: 20
        encoding: utf8

root:
    level: DEBUG
    handlers: [syslog, rotating_file]
    propogate: yes

loggers:
    main:
        level: DEBUG
        propogate: yes
```

When i get a logger by `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` for which there is no specific configuration, and log via `logger.fatal("Some log message...")`, i would expect the root logger to be used to log the message. But nothing is logged. But why?
Logging is configured this way:

```
log_config = yaml.safe_load(open('logger-cfg.yml'))
logging.config.dictConfig(log_config)
```

Comment: It logs something like `[54377] __main__(<module>:8) - CRITICAL: Some log message...` to `file.log`. If you are looking for something in console, you need to add a `StreamHandler` to the handlers.

Comment: @ShanavasM i doubled checked my question, but i nowhere mentioned that i expect the log message to arrive at the console. But yes, i would use a StreamHandler for that purpose :)